# Django ORM make a relation with tables depending on eah other (circular reference)

Tags: python, sql, django, django-models, django-orm

Firstly sorry if this question has already been made somewhere (I really couldn't find nothing after 1 hour of research).
How can I make a relation with tables depending in each other with Django ORM? e.g. The users belong to a shop and one of those users is the shop boss.

[Relation Image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/REpbS.png)

Comment: are you talking about foreign key !!

Answer (score 1):

this is an example how to create relation between two tables users and application where for each application a user creator. this code is part from application class :

```
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    description = models.TextField(max_length=1024)
    userid = models.ForeignKey(
        'package.Users',
        on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="applications",

    )
```

Comment: In case it isn’t clear, the key part is to quote the model class in the ForeignKey, making it a string that the ORM is smart enough to parse to avoid the need for an import.

Comment: The problem with ForeignKey is that it will allow a user have more than one shop...